# Link all haskell commands to different version

Tags: haskell

I recently installed ghc 7.8, but now I want to go back to ghc 7.4

I installed ghc 7.8 via a binary package, but I didn't uninstall it correctly. When I run `ghc`, `ghci` or `runhaskell`, I get

```
/usr/local/bin/ghc: line 9: /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.8.2/bin/ghc: No such file or directory
```

How do I change all these applications to point to the correct version (7.4) that's here?

```
/usr/bin/ghc-7.4.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the references using `update-alternatives`.

For example:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set ghc /usr/bin/ghc-7.4.1/ghc
sudo update-alternatives --set ghci /usr/bin/ghc-7.4.1/ghci
sudo update-alternatives --set runhaskell /usr/bin/ghc-7.4.1/runhaskell
```

[More information](http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives).